# Error after upgrading to JDK 8 on MAC

Tags: java, macos, java-8

After upgrading to JDK 8 on Mac, I get the following error when I try and check the java version. Can anyone help me sort it out?

```
MAC30880443:Versions t821714$ java -version
Error occurred during initialization of VM
java/lang/ClassNotFoundException: error in opening JAR file <Zip file open error> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_75.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed/jaxb-api-2.2.12.jar
```

Comment: Does the file path specified exist? My guess is not. You must be missing a dependancy, or the one you previously had is not compatible with JDK8.

Comment: I think it does exist. It looks to me like it is pointing at the old version - jdk1.7.0_75.jdk instead of the newly installed one.

Comment: Oh yes, look at that.
Have you changed your `$JAVA_HOME` environmental variable to point to the java 8 jdk?

Comment: How do I change the $JAVA_HOME environmental variable?

Comment: Try entering this in your OSX terminal. `echo "export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home">>~/.profile && . ~/.profile` this will append a line to your .profile setting the new home variable, and then resourcing your profile. Then run `java -version` again and tell me your results.

Comment: YES! thank you Matt. That worked. Please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would appear as if the new JDK got installed, however your `JAVA_HOME` environmental variable appears to be either unset, or still set to use JDK 7.

To check its current value, you can execute `echo $JAVA_HOME`

To update the value for your current terminal session, you can execute `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home`.

If you want the above snippet to run every time you start a new terminal session, you can enter the following, which will append it to your `.profile`

```
echo "export /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home" >> ~/.profile
. ~/.profile
```

The second line will source that .profile line to load the variables set in it.

Cheers, and happy coding.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like your java PATH is messed up, setting it varies based on OS version so take a look [here](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-environment-variable-on-mac-os-x/) and make sure it is set properly.

if you are running os 10+ all you have to do is

```
echo export "JAVA_HOME=\$(/usr/libexec/java_home)" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

or if you think you know better than apple and are sure your java_home is in the default location, use:

```
echo "export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home" >> ~/.bash_profile
```

then do

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

also make sure java 8 is set in the top of your preferences. (Utilities -> Java Preferences -> General). Click and drag it to the top of the list if it is not there, otherwise you might continue to use the older version of java

Comment: Hi Epicblood, please refrain from using Link Only answers. Please click [edit] and add relevant content from the link to your post body.